# How to unit test a server that's listening asynchronously

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I've been passed a bit of code that needs to have some unit tests added to it.

The class in question is a Socket server that listens asynchronously for any clients attempting to connect and adds them to a list of sockets to listen to for data. Obviously there's more to it than that but that should be enough to get started with.

The outline of the class goes:

```
public class MyServer
{
    private Socket _Server;
    private List<MyClient> _clients;

    public int ClientCount
    {
        _clients.Count;
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        _Server = new Socket(...)
        ... // Configure the socket
        _Server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AddPotentialClient), null);
    }

    private void AddPotentialClient(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        var newClient = new MyClient(clientSocket);

        _clients.Add(newClient);
    }
}
```

As a starting place I first want to check that the number of enrolled clients (ClientCount) increases by 1 when a client is successfully enrolled. As it stands the code doesn't make unit testing very easy so I started off by introducing an ISocket interface and SocketAdapter wrapper to help with mocking. I then modified the `StartListening()` method so that a Mock could be injected, like so:

```
public void StartListening(ISocket server)
{
    _Server = server;
    _Server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AddPotentialClient), null);
}
```

This is where I'm getting stuck though. I can spin up a mock, I can get the mock into the class and I know what I want to check but how should I be configuring the Mock(s) to stimulate the increment I'm checking for. I don't want to be assuming anything about the internal state of the MyServer class if possible and I'm happy to refactor the existing code if it'll help to make the testing easier.

So far I've got the following for my test using moq:

```
[Test]
public void ClientConnecting_Increments_ClientCountBy1()
{
    var testServer = new MyServer();
    var mockASyncResult = new Mock<IAsyncResult>();
    var mockSocket = new Mock<ISocket>();

    // mockASyncResult needs to be configured so that it can be cast to an <ISocket>

    // Forwards configured mockASyncResult to AddPotentialClient() method
    mockSocket.Setup(x => x.BeginAccept(It.IsAny<AsyncCallack>(), null))
              .Returns(mockASyncResult.Object);

    _manager.StartListening(mockSocket.Object);

    Assert.That(_manager.ClientCount, Is.EqualTo(ONE_CLIENT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing I use [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.github.io) library.
You can fake your `ISocket` instance:

```
ISocket server = A.Fake<ISocket>();
A.CallTo(() => server.BeginAccept(A<AsyncCallback>.Ignored, null)
 .ReturnsLazily((AsyncCallback callback) => callback(null));

myServer.StartListening(server);
```